# Array of promises never gets resolved

Tags: javascript, promise

On my current project the Q library is used, and I have to collect data from several promises to complete the operation.
I'm trying to use Q.all() method, but it looks like final promise is pending forever.
Example code is

```
Q.all([
  getSomeData('table', 'record1'),
  getSomeData('table', 'record2'),
  getSomeData('table', 'record3')
]).then(processData, handleError);
```

Every `getSomeData` returns a Q promise. Neither `processData` nor `handleError` is called finally, and if I save the final promise I see the status "pending" on it.
If I run all these promises separately, all of them are fulfilled successfully. If I run `Q.all` with only one promise (any of them) it fulfills successfully. But running `Q.all` with two or more promises is always unsuccessful.
What can cause such an issue? What additional information is required?

Comment: Can you run that 'final promise' alone and see if it resolves?

Comment: Any network errors? Rate limiting comes into mind, especially launching multiple requests in parallel.

Comment: Please show us the implementation of `getSomeData`. Maybe you have a mistake there that prevents concurrent execution, or swallows errors, or something else.

Comment: could be some "accidental global" in `getSomeData`

Comment: There are no network or any other errors. But final promise doesn't resolve, it is in pending state forever.
Sorry, I can't show implementation of `getSomeData` due to company restrictions, but I can have close look at potential issues that could appear here. Accidental global is a good starting point. Anyway I can't change this implementation. Maybe I'll just understand it can't be solved with existing implementation, so I'd just use chaining.

Comment: Sorry for long silence, actually the issue is with getSomeData implementation. If I run it several times one by one, only the last one gets resolved. As I can't change implementation I just use different way to get data. Thank you everyone!